# Sumar los valores de una columna en Mysql e imprimir el resultado en php

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas Noches espero que me puedan colaborar en lo siguiente. Tengo la siguiente tabla en Mysql:

```
productos->nombre de la tabla
nombre->campo
valor->campo
```

Tengo el siguiente php

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT nombre,valor FROM productos";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
$suma=0;
?>
<tbody>
<?php

while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

?>
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $mostrar[0] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $mostrar[1] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $mostrar[2] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $suma ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
$suma+=$mostrar[2];
}
?>
```

Al mirar como queda, veo que hace la suma correcta, sin embargo hace lo siguiente:

```
NOMBRE  VALOR   TOTAL
A        500      0
B        300     500
C        200     800
```

Muestra el resultado de la suma al tercer registro y el ultimo no lo suma. Como puedo arreglar esto para que muestre el resultado de una sola vez y no haga esto?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: La fila C debe quedar C | 200 | 1000 ?

Comment: Tendias que usar una consulta de suma: `SELECT SUM(valor) as valor FROM productos`. De hacerlo tendrias como resultado `1000`

Comment: sebastian no,al hacerla asi si mostraria pero quedaria a =1000 y b y c se desaparecen y al hacer el select traeria solo el primer resultado con toda la suma por eso puse el resultado en una variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el orden donde haces la suma

```
<?php 
            while ( $mostrar=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                $suma+=$mostrar[2];
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar[0] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar[1] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar[2] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $suma ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: ya habia probado y hace lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias amigo si era por ubicacion tenia todo bien excepto eso.